# Cannot get pictures from medialibrary

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8

I am using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media on my Windows Phone 8 app.
I have Many pictures in my CameraRoll and several in "Saved Image". 
But I cannot get pictures from MediaLibrary.
It always returns an empty set in MediaLibrary.Pictures.

Here is the Output in the "Immediate Window":

```
{Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PictureCollection}
    Count: 0
    IsDisposed: false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add the required `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO` capability to your app manifest?

Also, if you're using the emulator, it may be a good idea to first enter the Pictures app and only then testing your own app!

Comment: Just Googled "ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO". Didn't know that was needed. Added it to WMAppManifest. And yes, I need to enter the Pictures app first to get those pictures! Everything's worked perfectly. Thanks! Upvote!